# Xamarin IOs, Private key is encrypted but passphrase is empty when connecting to Mac Build Agent from Visual Studio for Windows

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am using a Mac with Parallels Desktop installed to build my Xamarin.IOs app in Visual Studio for Windows 2017 (Professional). I have two windows accounts in the Windows that runs in Parallels Desktop.

I used Visual Studio in one windows account and successfully connected to the Mac Build agent. But when I switched back to the other windows account and used the same Visual Studio application, I get an error when connecting to the Mac Build agent saying,

> Private key is encrypted but passphrase is empty...

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems like this is a bug in Visual Studio 2017.

I had to delete the,

- id_rsa
- id_rsa.pub
- passphrase.key

files found in my Windows account at **%LOCALAPPDATA%\Xamarin\MonoTouch** and reconnect to the Mac Build Agent.

Then it started working fine

**NOTE**:
I found this solution from [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/282099/vs2017-cant-connect-to-mac-private-key-is-encrypte.html)

Comment: Yes this works, happened today with VS 2019 v16.0.2